# How do I get the sub categories of the parent when in a sub category?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, categories

Im having an issue with a widget I'm building.

It shows you the sub categories of the selected category page and displays them in a list like so.

appologies for the subject of the site.

[image]

But when I click on a sub category let says Bondage Kits

It hides away the other categories and shows the sub categories of the selected but there are none.

[image]

Ideally when you select the sub category it should show the other categories within the parent.

PHP code got it almost working just dont know how to show the sub categories of the parent of the selected category.

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {


    $title   = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $title ) )
        echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

    $cate = get_queried_object();
    $cateID = $cate->term_id;
    $cateNM = $cate->name;

    $wcatTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 1, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'parent' => $cateID, )); 

    //echo get_category_parents( $cateID, true, '<br/>' );

    echo '<ul style="padding: 0px 10px;" class="product-categories"><li class="cat-item cat-parent">';
    echo '<a style="color: #1e1d1d ;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 1.7;padding: 2px 0 2px 3px;margin: 0;font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif;" href="#">' . $cateNM . '</a>';
    echo '<ul style="padding-left: 15px;" class="children">';

    foreach($wcatTerms as $wcatTerm) : 
   ?>

        <li style="color: #1e1d1d;" class="cat-item">
            <a  style="color: #1e1d1d;" href="<?php echo get_term_link( $wcatTerm->slug, $wcatTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $wcatTerm->name; ?></a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; 
       echo '</ul></li></ul>';
    echo $args['after_widget'];


}
```

The rest of my widget works fine this is just the output function.

the end result should be like.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you click?

Comment: it goes through to the sub category selected then attempts to get the sub categories from the selected. its the image where it says bondage kits. site here https://goo.gl/J8v6gz click on a sub category and it disappears when you goto the page.